# Reading and Writing to a plist file

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, plist

I need to write to a plist file and then read out the data again later...
However, whenever I test my app, the data written to the plist file is never saved after I quit the iphone simulator!! Could you tell me the reason as to why this problem exists? During runtime, the data seems to be written and read perfectly fine. But my plist file is never updated!
I might be doing this wrong. So could you please guide me through creating a plist in cocos2d and reading and writing integers to it?
Thank you!

Comment: Let's see your code; otherwise it's a complete guess as to what the problem is.

Comment: you definitely dream big idream...

Answer (score 0):

**To save:**

```
+ (void)save:(Example *)exampleobject {
     NSString * directory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString * path = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Example.plist"];
     [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:exampleobject toFile:path];
}
```

**To retrieve**

```
+ (Example *)load {
     NSString * directory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString * path = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Example.plist"];
     NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
     Example * exampleobject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
     if (!exampleobject) { exampleobject = [[Example alloc] init]; }
     return exampleobject;
}
```